# Using <form> how would I pass data to another html page without opening the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a RSVP form that I just want to store that data into a list on another html page called rsvplist.html without opening the page rsvplist.html

I am only using rsvplist.html as a way to store what people are submitting.

I currently do not have any JavaScript yet because I am not sure how to best approach this.

html:

```
<form id="fs-frm" name="basic-rsvp-form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="rsvplist.html" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fs-frm-inputs">
        <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="full-name" placeholder="First and Last" required="">
        <label for="attending">Will you Attend?</label>
        <select name="attending" id="attending" required="">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <label for="plus">And with how many guests?</label>
        <select name="plus" id="plus" required="">
            <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" id="email-subject" value="RSVP">
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="RSVP">
</form>
```

and just in case here is the CSS used for the form:

```
/*
*RSVP Form
*/
#fs-frm input,
#fs-frm select,
#fs-frm textarea,
#fs-frm fieldset,
#fs-frm optgroup,
#fs-frm label,
#fs-frm #card-element:disabled {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
#fs-frm label,
#fs-frm legend,
#fs-frm ::placeholder {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding-top: .2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

/* border, padding, margin, width */
#fs-frm input,
#fs-frm select,
#fs-frm textarea,
#fs-frm #card-element {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  padding: .75em 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#fs-frm input:focus,
#fs-frm select:focus,
#fs-frm textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: thin;
  outline-color: gray;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
#fs-frm [type="text"],
#fs-frm [type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
}
#fs-frm [type="button"],
#fs-frm [type="submit"],
#fs-frm [type="reset"] {
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
}
#fs-frm [type="button"]:focus,
#fs-frm [type="submit"]:focus,
#fs-frm [type="reset"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#fs-frm [type="submit"],
#fs-frm [type="reset"] {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#fs-frm select {
  text-transform: none;
}

#fs-frm [type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  appearance: checkbox;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0 !important;
}

#fs-frm [type="radio"] {
  -webkit-appearance: radio;
  -moz-appearance: radio;
  appearance: radio;
}

/* address, locale */
#fs-frm fieldset.locale input[name="city"],
#fs-frm fieldset.locale select[name="state"],
#fs-frm fieldset.locale input[name="postal-code"] {
  display: inline;
}
#fs-frm fieldset.locale input[name="city"] {
  width: 52%;
}
#fs-frm fieldset.locale select[name="state"],
#fs-frm fieldset.locale input[name="postal-code"] {
  width: 20%;
}
#fs-frm fieldset.locale input[name="city"],
#fs-frm fieldset.locale select[name="state"] {
  margin-right: 3%;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I would do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database

Comment: "_to store what people are submitting_" does this mean you want to _synchronize_ the form inputs? Are you looking for a client solution or a server solution? This seems as an opinion based question to me.

Comment: your form redirects to `rsvplist.html` already, I think you just need a server side programming language to be able to read the POST data from your form. You could also use GET which means the data is stored in the query string of the URL.
If you need this data to persist in other pages during the user's session you could use the browser's local storage

Comment: You could always `stringify` your responses and store them into `localStorage`. But that kinda limits all the data collected only to that one user. Not sure if that's what you're looking for here.

Comment: what I mean by store is create <li> in `rsvplist.html` using the values from the form. `rsvplist.html` will only be used for me to see the list of names created by the form. I really don't need a database because I am just needing the list of names. Sorry I shouldn't have used the word "store".

Comment: could I use an `<iframe src="rsvplist.html" style="display:none"></iframe>` and then use `appendChild(document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.getElementById('elementIdRsvpPage').createTextNode(userInput)` to create a `<li>`

Comment: I was really hoping for an easy solution but this idea will not work through just javaScript. I have to learn php and databases. Then have that database list be posted to `rsvpList.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned some PHP and MySQL, which wasn't as hard as I thought it would be, to come up with this solution.

First I created a MySQL Database on the server hosting the website. I then created a table in the database called `rsvpListTable`. I then created three columns named `guest_name`, `attending`, and `plus`.

In this I will be using the generic `USER_NAME` `PASSWORD` `DB_NAME` for accessing the database. Keep in mind those are not the real values.

in `index.php`:

```
<form id="fs-frm" name="basic-rsvp-form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#rsvpPage" method="post">
    <fieldset id="fs-frm-inputs">
        <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="guest_name" id="full-name" placeholder="First and Last" required="">
        <label for="attending">Will you Attend?</label>
        <select name="attending" id="attending" required="">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <label for="plus">And with how many guests?</label>
        <select name="plus" id="plus" required="">
            <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
</form>

<?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", "DB_NAME");
 
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("<p>ERROR: Could not connect.</p>");
    }
 
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $guest_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['guest_name']);
    $attending = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['attending']);
    $plus = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['plus']);
 
    // Attempt insert query execution

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO rsvpListTable (guest_name, attending, plus) VALUES ('$guest_name', '$attending', '$plus') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attending = VALUES(attending), plus = VALUES(plus)";
    
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            echo "<p>RSVP added successfully.</p>";
        } 
        else{
            echo "<p>ERROR: Could not execute $sql.</p>";
        }
    }
 
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Then to post the database contents on a separate page I created `rsvpList.php` and inside the `<body>` I put:

```
<?php 
$username = "USER_NAME"; 
$password = "PASSWORD"; 
$database = "DB_NAME"; 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM rsvpListTable";

echo '<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Attending?</th> 
        <th>How many guests?</th> 
    </tr>';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $guest_name = $row["guest_name"];
        $attending = $row["attending"];
        $plus = $row["plus"];

        echo '<tr> 
              <td>'.$guest_name.'</td> 
              <td>'.$attending.'</td> 
              <td>'.$plus.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
}

echo '</table>';

// Close connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

And that is basically my solution to this question.